# ADALiOS gives error while archiving from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode7, adal

I have integrated `ADALiOS` into my app. Its woking fine in simulator as well as in device also but while creating a build from `Xcode` or archiving, it shows an error. Here is the error-

> cp:
>   /Users/shashankmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleADWorkSpace-bescefcakmluwugktvayiqiqirzz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SampleADToken/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/Headers/ADALiOS/:
>   No such file or directory

Please give me some extension or suggestion regarding the same. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: include needed headers

Comment: As per my knowledge I have almost all required headers. If there is any specific one please let me know. I will add that too in my project

Comment: hello guys, same problem here. What the solution?

Comment: @CCastro: What I have done before is, I have created a workspace which contains two apps and I have integrated ADALiOS into the workspace.So that both the apps can use ADALiOS. But while archiving I was getting this error. So the solution is I have integrated ADALiOS separately in both the apps and it archived.

Comment: @shashank thks for share, I will try.

Comment: @shashank When you say "integrated ADALIOS" what did you do?

Comment: @CCastro: I just copied all the files into the project.

Comment: @shashank Oh ok. I think was something more complex. What your ADALIOS version? Are you using cocoapods?

Comment: @CCastro: Convergence_Dev branch B2C. No I am not using cocoapods , just manually copied all the files into the project.